# How to get notified about DatePicker ValueHelp event?

Tags: sapui5

I need to be able to know when the DatePicker's value help button is pressed and the calendar shows up.

[image: datepicker button that fires event (open calendar)]

But there is not any reference in the docs of how to do this.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53817935/5846045

Answer (score 2):

You can use the navigate event to do this. First, declare the datepicker in the view (Below example for xml view) and give the callback for the navigate event.

```
<DatePicker id="some_date" navigate="onClickDate"/>
```

Then, give declaration for the callback function in your controller for this view.

```
onClickDate: function(){
    //do something
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `navigate` event, but then that will also fire again each time the user navigates in the calendar.

Technically, you could use the `press` event of the value help icon (`oDatePicker._getValueHelpIcon().attachPress()`), but that would probably be frowned upon as it uses a private method of the control.

Comment: About the `navigate` event; an additional parameter will be available in the upcoming versions to distinguish the behaviors. Here is a demo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53817935/5846045

Answer (score 1):

You can use **"isOpen()"** for when the dates are revealed or **"getValue()"** to get the last selected value on the calendar and returned by the change event, other methods are available here>> [DatePicker Methods](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.DatePicker/methods/Summary)

```js
//DatePicker View.js
var datePicker = new DatePicker(this.createId("calendarSelect"), {
  width: "80%",
  maxDate: new Date(),
  valueFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd",
  displayFormat: "long",
  change: function() {
    oController.someFunction();
  },
  value: new Date().toDateString("en-GB")
});

//DatePicker Controller.js
someFunction: function() {
  console.log(this.getView().byId("calendarSelect").isOpen()); // returns true or false when the calendar is open 
  console.log(this.getView().byId("calendarSelect").getValue()); //to get value selected 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the target UI5 version, the control provides ValueHelp-related events to which you can attach your handlers.

```xml
<DatePicker xmlns="sap.m"
  navigate=".onNavigate"
  afterValueHelpOpen=".onAfterValueHelpOpen"
  afterValueHelpClose=".onAfterValueHelpClose"
/><!-- Applies also to sap.m.DateTimePicker and sap.m.DateRangeSelection -->
```

```js
onNavigate: function(event) { // Since 1.46
  const isFiredAfterPopupOpened = event.getParameter("afterPopupOpened"); // Since 1.62
  // ...
},
onAfterValueHelpOpen: function() { // Since 1.102
  // ...
},
onAfterValueHelpClose: function() { // Since 1.102
  // ...
},
```

Here is a demo:

```js
globalThis.onUI5Init = () => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/m/DatePicker",
], (DP, MsgToast) => new DP({
  placeholder: "Press F4 or click on -->",
  navigate: e => e.getParameter("afterPopupOpened") && console.log("Event: navigate", "with afterPopupOpened: true"),
  afterValueHelpOpen: () => console.log("Event:"," afterValueHelpOpen"),
  afterValueHelpClose: () => console.log("Event: afterValueHelpClose"),
  width: "16rem",
}).addStyleClass("sapUiTinyMargin").placeAt("content"));
```

```html
<script defer id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m,sap.ui.unified"
  data-sap-ui-oninit="onUI5Init"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_horizon"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-excludejquerycompat="true"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

The events `afterValueHelpOpen` and `afterValueHelpClose` are also available for `sap.m.TimePicker` since UI5 1.102.